# Find the log file when Spring cloud dataflow server runs

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I am running spring cloud dataflow server 2.6.0 as a docker container and I want to know the folder in the container where the server log file will be.

I understand that this file is being used to configure logging for dataflow server.
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/blob/master/spring-cloud-dataflow-server/src/main/resources/logback-spring.xml

However, I was not able to find the actual file anywhere inside the docker container.

Where is this log file located in the container and if some examples are provided which clearly explains how the different properties like LOG_PATH, LOG_FILE etc affect this file location/name , it would be very helpful.

Also, how do I change the logging level for the logs that are printed on the console/file when dataflow server runs? I tried using DEBUG=true as an environment variable and it did not work. I only see info logs right now.

Answer (score 0):

The default logback configuration you pointed at above uses `ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender` with the specific size on rolling over. It is possible that you haven't got the threshold reached to generate the log file.

You can verify this with a simple `FileAppender` logging configuration in the logback config as follows:

```
 <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>scdf.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
 </appender>
```

and see if the logs are available inside the docker container. I just verified this on using docker-compose with the above setting on my SCDF container image as well.

Since SCDF also configures the console log appender, you can use the `docker logs <container-id>` to get the logs as well.